# EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to save my entity but this error occurs to me after changing the class ID from long to Long

I don't know why but hibernate doesn't save the object and thymeleaf sees that the ID field is null

Should I change it back to long ?

(Something strange)

I opened the debugger to see where the problem occurs

after calling `EntityManager.persist()` an ID is assigned to the object but it throws an exception saying that the object couldn't be saved

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It means hibernate is not able to generate an id for the record.

Ensure that you are using `@Id` annotation and `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` on id field and have proper getter/setters.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I have some data that needs to be imported I used 
`@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=85000)`


`@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")`

Comment: no problem..auto was just for example there..you can use any type of generation strategy

Comment: Then all the required annotations, getters, and setters are in place.. what shall I do ?

Comment: use @Transactional on the DAO method and check once. also run em.flush() after persist

Comment: Still no change, once persist is run the code throws a PersistenceException and it doesn't reach neither flush nor commit

Comment: Delete the table and let hibernate create again if no critical data.